# Is it true Lord Shiva had incarnations too?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, shiva-purana, vishnu-purana

Unlike Vishnu Lord Shiva had no incarnations ? If he did then apart from the Rudra in the form of Hanuman what other forms did Lord Shiva incarnate as ?